# DDD Microservice Saving releated service data

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I have product service, category service, promotions service, search service.

When User want to add product. CreateProductRequest come to product service. Request includes product data and  datas of other services like categoryId,uncalculated price , too. After product is added. I need to send other servie datas. Category service needs productId and CategoryId. Promotions service needs productId and price.

After creat eproduct transaction commited;

1) I put all data in ProductCreatedEvent that includes saved productId, categoryId, uncalculated price etc. Every service get what it needs from event and save to own db. I publish event with RabbitMQ

2) Send via seperated commands to services.I send commands  with RabbitMQ

And What If there is no category that id  come with event and Category services didn't save. But Product saved at product Services ?

or what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, it's important to keep in mind the difference between a command and event. A command is a request to do something. An event is a record of something that has happened. One key difference is that a command can be rejected.

When looking at your use case, publishing events to other services makes the most sense. The product has been created and you are notifying the other bounded contexts that care about the change. If you issue a command, you are telling other bounded context to make a change that may or may not fail.

That said, you each bounded context may receive the event and produce a command within their own context to update aggregates managed within. As such, the difference is subtle between these two:
- Issue a command to each bounded context
- Issue an event to each bounded context and they can then trigger a command as needed

But given the above, the notification of the creation of the product should not fail. It has happened already. From there, each context can decide what to do about it.